# Does protection let me block something that can't be blocked?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

My friend has a sorcery that makes it so a creature can't be blocked but I have a creature that has protection from all creatures. If he attacked me with his creature that can't be blocked, does my protection from creatures not nullify that?

Comment: Hey!  Welcome to B&CG!  Please consider editing in the exact cards you are dealing with, just in case it helps our gurus come up with an answer for you.

Comment: @PatLudwig Does it matter? One card has "cannot be blocked", the other has "protection from creatures". It's easy enough to name some cards with these attributes. If there are more attributes in play, then it'd be a different question.

Comment: @Allure Correct, it is easy enough to name them which means it should be easy enough to include them in the question when asking. Knowing exactly which cards  the person is asking about can help make sure everyone is on the same page and a correct answer is given.

Comment: @JoeW I have asked questions like [Is Boseiju, who Endures' channel ability blocked by protection from green?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/57505/is-boseiju-who-endures-channel-ability-blocked-by-protection-from-green) without specifying what card it is that is granting Protection from Green, I think requesting the specific cards in this case is unfair.

Comment: Yeah the actual cards don't matter here; the effect does and it's unambiguously described.

Comment: @PatLudwig That isn't important here since the question is about interaction of common keywords/abilities, it's not important to know the creature with protection from [color] and the unblockable creature are (for example) specifically Beloved Chaplain and River Sneak respectively to know how cards with those abilities (don't) interact.

Answer (score 10):

No, protection will not do anything in this case.

Protection helps with 4 specific things and nothing else. A creature with protection   [from quality] cannot be:

- **D**amaged, by sources with that quality (the damage is prevented).
- **E**nchanted / Equipped / Fortified, by cards with that quality.
- **B**locked, by creatures with that quality.
- **T**argeted, by spells or abilities from sources with that quality.

Although #3, cannot be blocked by, is related to blocking, it does not allow you to block an unblockable creature. Protection does not do anything outside of these things.